# Iterate 2 tables to show difference of each row element in a popup

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have 3 tables and at a moment I am selecting any 2 tables and I want to show the difference of each row element of selected tables in a popup in a different column along with the tables .I am stuck here how to compute the difference between the each row of two selected tables. How can i iterate both the tables and then get the result?

```js
var selectedRows = document.getElementsByClassName('selected');
        limit = 0; //set limit

        checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.checkboxdiv input[type="checkbox"]');
        function checker(elem) {
            if (elem.checked) {
                limit++;
            } else {
                limit--;
            }

            for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {

                if (limit == 2) {
                    if (!checkboxes[i].checked) {
                        checkboxes[i].disabled = true;

                    }

                } else {

                    if (!checkboxes[i].checked) {
                        checkboxes[i].disabled = false;
                    }

                }
            }

        }

        for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
            checkboxes[i].onclick = function () {
                checker(this);
            }
        }

        var checkedArray;
        function myFunction(event) {
            event.target.parentElement.parentElement.className =
                event.target.checked ? 'selected' : '';

            var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
            checkedArray = new Array();
            for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                if (elements[i].type === 'checkbox' && elements[i].checked) {
                    checkedArray.push(elements[i].id);
                }
            }
            console.log(checkedArray);
        }
        function clickbtn() {
            // var table;
            // for (let i = 0; i < checkedArray.length; i++) {
            //  console.log("c", checkedArray[i])
            //  table = new Array();
            //  for (let i = 0; i < checkedArray.length; i++) {
            //      table.push("table" + checkedArray[i])

            //  }
            //  console.log(table)
            // }
            // for (let i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {

            //  var t1 = document.getElementById(table[i]);
            //  var t2 = document.getElementById(table[i + 1]);


            // }
            const buildTable = (arr) => {
                let table = document.querySelector("#diff-table");
                if (table) table.remove();

                table = document.createElement("table");
                table.id = "diff-table";
                const thead = document.createElement("thead"),
                    thA = document.createElement("th"),
                    thB = document.createElement("th"),
                    thDiff = document.createElement("th");
                thA.innerText = "Plan A";
                thB.innerText = "Plan B";
                thDiff.innerText = "Difference";
                thead.append(thA, thB, thDiff);
                table.append(thead);

                arr.forEach((i) => {
                    const tr = document.createElement("tr"),
                        tdA = document.createElement("td"),
                        tdB = document.createElement("td"),
                        tdDiff = document.createElement("td");
                    tdA.innerText = "$" + i["planA"];
                    tdB.innerText = "$" + i["planB"];
                    tdDiff.innerText = "$" + i["diff"];
                    tr.append(tdA, tdB, tdDiff);
                    table.append(tr);
                });

                document.body.append(table);
            };
            const checked = document.querySelectorAll(":checked"),
                arr = [];
            if (checked.length !== 2) return;

            const planA = document
                .querySelector(":checked:first-of-type")
                .closest("table")
                .querySelectorAll("td");
            const planB = document
                .querySelector(":checked:last-of-type")
                .closest("table")
                .querySelectorAll("td");

            planA.forEach((cell, i) => {
                const valA = +cell.innerText.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '');
                const valB = +planB[i].innerText.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '');
                arr.push(valA - valB);
            });

            buildTable(arr);

            

        }
```

```css
.table_container{
        float:left;
        width:25%;
    }
    .container::after{  
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
    }
    table{
        margin: 0 auto; 
        
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
    tr{
        padding: 15px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    td{
        color: black;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        border: 1px double white;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: #e1edf9;
        width:272px;
    }
    .sub_text{
        font-size: 12px;
        font-style: italic;
        color: #0071ce;
        font-weight: 100;
    }
    th{
        background-color: #0071ce;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px;
        border-top-left-radius: 10px;
        border-top-right-radius: 10px;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .header{
        color: #0071ce;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 10px;
    }
```

Comment: I'm writing up a solution, I'll post in a few mins.

Comment: Given that I can't see any differences between any of the plans you show, what are you expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution I built.

*NOTES* I removed INLINE JS. You will have to design your own CSS for the newly created element called `#diff-table`. Also, this checks to make sure EXACTLY 2 plans were selected (if no plans, 1 plan, or 3 plans were selected, it will not run).

```
    const btn = document.querySelector("button");

    btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
      const checked = document.querySelectorAll(":checked"),
        arr = [];
      if (checked.length !== 2) return;

      const plans = document.querySelectorAll(":checked"),
        planA = plans[0].closest("table").querySelectorAll("td"),
        planB = plans[1].closest("table").querySelectorAll("td");

      planA.forEach((cell, i) => {
        const valA = +cell.innerText.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '');
        const valB = +planB[i].innerText.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '');
        arr.push({ planA: valA, planB: valB, diff: valA - valB });
      });

      buildTable(arr);
    });

    const buildTable = (arr) => {
      let table = document.querySelector("#diff-table");
      if (table) table.remove();

      table = document.createElement("table");
      table.id = "diff-table";
      const thead = document.createElement("thead"),
        thA = document.createElement("th"),
        thB = document.createElement("th"),
        thDiff = document.createElement("th");
      thA.innerText = "Plan A";
      thB.innerText = "Plan B";
      thDiff.innerText = "Difference";
      thead.append(thA, thB, thDiff);
      table.append(thead);

      arr.forEach((i) => {
        const tr = document.createElement("tr"),
          tdA = document.createElement("td"),
          tdB = document.createElement("td"),
          tdDiff = document.createElement("td");
        tdA.innerText = "$" + i["planA"];
        tdB.innerText = "$" + i["planB"];
        tdDiff.innerText = "$" + i["diff"];
        tr.append(tdA, tdB, tdDiff);
        table.append(tr);
      });

      document.body.append(table);
    };
```

Comment: Thanks But I am little confused here, are you not calling "clickbtn" function here?

Comment: Correct, I redesigned "clickbtn" function based on what you said you wanted to achieve. Instead, we are adding an event listener (listening for the "click" on the button) and running an anonymous function.

Comment: i tried this but I am getting undefined in the resulting table

Comment: Did you remove the inline JS from your HTML?

Comment: change ``<button onclick = "clickbtn()">Click Me</button>`` to ``<button>Click Me</button>``

Comment: I have instead called the code inside the function. Could you please see the edited snippet?

Comment: Oh you're right, there might be a typo in the code I posted. It works in my VS Code, let me check for differences

Comment: I found the issue. I forgot to update 1 line. I have edited the change.

Comment: Just before the ``buildTable(arr)`` function is called, there is a line:
``arr.push()``. This line has been updated to:
``arr.push({ planA: valA, planB: valB, diff: valA - valB });``

Comment: Yes I tried that also but the problem is it is alwasy taking the first selected table twice and then showing difference as 0.

Comment: Probably a small fix, let me check it. Sorry. The code you posted had the same values in all 3 tables.

Comment: Yes even if we will update any value, the table will always take first table twice and show the difference 0, but the expectation is to hve difference

Comment: Fixed the issue. I updated: ``const plans = document.querySelectorAll(":checked"),
    planA = plans[0].closest("table").querySelectorAll("td"),
    planB = plans[1].closest("table").querySelectorAll("td");``

Comment: The current Edit should address this issue. 
Also, it calculates the plans based on Left-most plan minus the Right-most plan, if you want to switch it, then replace ``diff: valA - valB`` with ``diff: valB - valA``

Hope this helps

Comment: I have the similar requirement but Instead of fixed header name I want my header to be the name of the table selected. For e.g here it is hard coded to Plan A and Plan B, if I want heading to be dynamic. How could that be achieved ? Can anyone please help?

Comment: Yea, I'll make some edits for you sometime this week when I get time. It's pretty simple, you just need to read the value of the table and pass it as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

`myTable1.querySelectorAll("td")` will give you list of `TD` from which you can extract the content:

```js
var checkedArray; 
function myFunction()
{
    
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
    checkedArray = new Array();
    for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++)
    {
        if(elements[i].type === 'checkbox' && elements[i].checked)
        {
            checkedArray.push(elements[i].value);
        }
    }
    console.log(checkedArray);
    var data = {}
    for (var i = 0; i < checkedArray.length; i++)
    {
      var table = document.getElementById(checkedArray[i]),
          td = table.querySelectorAll("td"),
          info = [];
      for(var t = 0; t < td.length; t++)
      {
        info[info.length] = td[t].textContent;
      }
      data[checkedArray[i]] = info;
    }
    console.log(data);
}
function clickbtn(){
  var table;
  for(let i=0; i< checkedArray.length; i++){
      console.log("c",checkedArray[i])
      table = new Array();
      for(let i=0; i< checkedArray.length; i++){
          table.push("table"+checkedArray[i])

      }
      console.log(table)
  }
  for(let i=0; i< table.length; i++){

      var t1 = document.getElementById(table[i]);
      var t2 = document.getElementById(table[i+1]);
      $('#t tr').each(function(){
        $(this).find('td').each(function(){

      })
    })
  }
}
```

```css
.table_container{
        float:left;
        width:25%;
    }
    .container::after{  
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
    }
    table{
        margin: 0 auto; 
        
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
    tr{
        padding: 15px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    td{
        color: black;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        border: 1px double white;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: #e1edf9;
        width:272px;
    }
    .sub_text{
        font-size: 12px;
        font-style: italic;
        color: #0071ce;
        font-weight: 100;
    }
    th{
        background-color: #0071ce;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px;
        border-top-left-radius: 10px;
        border-top-right-radius: 10px;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .header{
        color: #0071ce;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container"> 
<div class="table_container">
<table>
    <tr><th colspan="2">Cost</th></tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="header" rowspan="4">paycheck<br>
        <span class="sub_text">rates shown</span>
        </td>
    <td>Associate Only</td>
    <tr><td>A</td></tr>
    <tr><td>B</td></tr>
    <tr><td>C</td></tr>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="header" rowspan="2">Contribution<br>
        <span class="sub_text">
        </span>
        </td>
    <td>Associate</td>
    <tr><td>B</td></tr>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="header" rowspan="2">Annual<br>
        <span class="sub_text">in-network care</span>
        </td>
        <td>A</td>
    <tr><td>B</td></tr>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="header" rowspan="2">Max<br>
        <span class="sub_text">in-network care</span>
        </td>
    <td>Per person</td>
    <tr><td>Entire family</td></tr>
    </tr>
</table>    

</div>

<div class="table_container">
<table id="table1">
    <tr><th>Plan<input type="checkbox" id="1" name="table1" value="table1" onchange="myFunction()"> </th>
        
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>$33.90</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>$161.30</td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td>$53.30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>$186.20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>HSA match:up to $350</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>HSA match:up to $700</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>$3000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>$6000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>$6650</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>$13300</td>
    </tr>
</table>    
    </div>

<div class="table_container">
<table id="table2">
    <tr><th>Plan<input type="checkbox" id="2" name="table2" value="table2" onchange="myFunction()"></th>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>$33.90</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>$161.30</td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td>$53.30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>$186.20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>HSA match:up to $350</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>HSA match:up to $700</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>$3000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>$6000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>$6650</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>$13300</td>
    </tr>
</table>    
    </div>

<div class="table_container">
<table id="table3">
    <tr><th>Plan<input type="checkbox" id="3" name="table3" value="table3" onchange="myFunction()"> </th>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>$33.90</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>$161.30</td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td>$53.30</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>$186.20</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>HSA match:up to $350</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>HSA match:up to $700</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>$3000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>$6000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>$6650</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>$13300</td>
    </tr>
</table>    
    </div>
</div>
<button onclick = "clickbtn()">Click Me</button>
```